# NodeJS beside Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, virtualhost, vps

I know this kind of subject have been asking a lot of times, but i didn't find any answer that match my need. First, i apologize for my english.

I want to run a node application and a (or many) other usual web site on a VPS.
So tu host several web site on the same vps, i have to use virtualhost from apache right ? So that's what i've done : in */var/www* i have 2 directory : *test1* and *test2*. What i want is that test1 will be my node application, accessible with *test1.my_domain* and test2 will be a random other website accessible with *test2.my_domain*. To do that, i've configure apache like this :

/etc/apache2/sites_available/default :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin contact@my_domain
ServerName my_domain
ServerAlias www.my_domain

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites_available/test1.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin contact@my_domain
ServerName my_domain
ServerAlias test1.my_domain

DocumentRoot /var/www/test1
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/test1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites_available/test2.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin contact@my_domain
ServerName my_domain
ServerAlias test2.my_domain

DocumentRoot /var/www/test2
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/test2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration work perfectly if test1 is not node application. I mean that when i go to *test1.my_domain*, i get the content of */var/www/test1* and if i go to *test2.my_domain*, I get the content of */var/www/test2*.

But if I put a node application in test1, node enter in conflict with apache because they both use the port 80.

I have seen many tutorial to solve that by using apache's proxys but i can't figure out how to use it well.
I precise that i can make node listen to an other port than 80 but i don't whant to do that because if i do the url will be *test1.my_domain:7777* (for example), and it's ugly right ?

Also i'm a beginner in the domain of vps configuration so please describe your answer as much as you can ;).

Thank's guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run node app on port 7777, and use this as `test1.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin contact@my_domain
ServerName test1.my_domain

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:7777/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:7777/

</VirtualHost>
```

With this, your node app should be reachable with `http://test1.my_domain`

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, i will try it later. But with this configuration how the server know that http://test1.my_domain is in /var/www/test1 ?

Comment: apache doesn't care where node _files_ are (or if it is node app, tomcat server or whatever), it will simply forward any request for test1.my_domain to app that is running on port 7777

Comment: btw, this is **very** common setup, you are not the first with this requirement :)

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it still doesn't work. My node application use socket.io : 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Socket.io</title>
    </head>
 
    <body>
        <h1>Communication avec socket.io !</h1>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('test1.my_domain');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>` 
instead of test1.my_domain I have tried test1.localhost:7777 and test1.my_domain:7777 but it didn't worked.

Comment: Wel, first you need to have your node app running on port 7777. Can you open it from browser with  http://test1.my_domain:7777 ?

Comment: Yep it work if i use http://test1.my_domain:7777 with `var socket = io.connect('test1.my_domain:7777')`.

Comment: OK, what do you get in browser when you try `http://test1.my_domain`, while node is running with `var socket = io.connect('test1.my_domain:7777')`

Comment: Here is what i get : `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, contact@thomascrenn.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at test1.crenn.net Port 80`

Comment: In the logs i got : `[Fri Sep 09 13:09:41 2016] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Fri Sep 09 13:09:41 2016] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /favicon.ico. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`

Comment: EDIT: Ok i made it worked with `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` ! Thank you very much for the help ;)

Comment: Ah, good. I was starting to get confused why is it not working :)